# How to loop and output the attributes of more than one object in CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

This is what I'm doing right now:

```
"click .save-file": (e) ->
  posts = Posts.find().fetch()
  console.log post for post in posts
```

Which outputs:

> Object {_id: "jMraqpqyAcHz9BCM4", title: "Post 1", position: 3}
>   
>   Object {_id: "7dsT8RpsPZ3LfjisX", title: "Post
>   3", position: 2}

How can I modify the code above so that it outputs:

> Post 1 
>  3
>
> Post 3 
>  2

Instead? (I think I have to do something like: `"#{@title}\n\n#{@position}"`)

Comment: did either answer below work for you? If so, could you please accept one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try...

```
"click .save-file": (e) ->
  posts = Posts.find().fetch()
  for post in posts
    console.log post.title
    console.log post.position
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to use is `"#{post.title}\n#{post.position}\n"` since `@` references `this` and you need to reference `post`.

Comment: I tried this: `"#{post.title}\n#{post.position}\n" post for post in posts` but got: `unexpected post`